# Using display property to show/hide div inside an accordion causes the div to be displayed permanently

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap accordion (ver. 5.0) inside of which are several buttons. When the user clicks on one of the buttons, I want the div inside of the accordion to change. I am currently using the display style property, alternating between show and hide as appropriate using javascript. The problem is that once the display property has been set to show, the div is shown even when the accordion is collapsed closed. Is there any way to solve this issue apart from writing a set of instructions to hide the div on collapse, as this would likely override the default accordion animation?

```
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#options">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="options_heading">Options</h2>
        </button>

        <div id="options" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#account_info">
            <button class="btn" id="password_change">Change Password</button>
        </div>

        <div id="p_change" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#account_info" style="display: none;">
            <!-- password change form here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to switch between the div with the form and the div with the options. I'm using vanilla javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: Possibly you need to have another accordion within this accordion-item, to show/hide the various options?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: I think the correct use of the Bootstrap accordion is to have only one element within it to collapse/show. The best solution would probably be to dynamically change the content of the single `.accordion-item .accordion-collapse` when the relevant button is pressed.